# Does the following code cause deadlock when running

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

When running the following code, the *main thread* is *locked* on the *instance* of `MainDealock` infinitely

```
    public class MainDeadlock {
      public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        wait();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new MainDeadlock().lock();
      }
    }
```

However, I can not figure out any *circular wait* as there is only one thread, i.e. the *main thread*

**Question: May I still say there is a *deadlock* in this case?**

Comment: A deadlock necessarily involves 2 or more threads, so no it's not a deadlock. Did you read the JavaDoc for `Object.wait`? "Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the `notify()` method". There is no other thread doing this. Think of it more as an infinite loop.

Comment: Some people say, "liveness failure," to describe a situation like this where a thread gets stuck for a reason that can not properly be called "deadlock." Other people just say that the thread is "hung," or "stuck," or "wedged," or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need at least 2 threads for a deadlock, where they keep each other from progressing because they’re each holding onto something the other needs.

This  code doesn’t hold onto a lock. For a thread to call wait it must have the lock, but once it begins waiting it releases the lock.

All you have here is a thread waiting on a notify that never comes. When you call wait with no timeout specified then the thread will go dormant until:

- some other thread calls notify on the lock that the waiting thread used to call wait, or
- until another thread calls interrupt on the waiting thread or
- until you get tired of it and kill the process.